# CSS rotating squares causing height flexing -- Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I am working on a codepen which involves some circles that rotate. It seems that in Chrome only, the rotation causes flexing in the height of the document. To understand what I just said, view what I have so far and scroll to the bottom and watch as everything expands and contracts in height.
Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/www139/pen/XXpQwx?editors=110).
Please let me know if you don't understand the question.

```css
/*loader 1*/

.loader1 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: relative;
  -o-animation: loaderRotate 2s infinite ease-in;
  -moz-animation: loaderRotate 2s infinite ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: loaderRotate 2s infinite ease-in;
  -ms-animation: loaderRotate 2s infinite ease-in;
  animation: loaderRotate 2s infinite ease-in;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
.loader1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid #FF3E31;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.loader1:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid #FF3E31;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-animation: borderFlexLoader 2.5s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: borderFlexLoader 2.5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: borderFlexLoader 2s infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: borderFlexLoader 2.5s infinite linear;
  animation: borderFlexLoader 2s infinite linear;
}
@-o-keyframes loaderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loaderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loaderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes loaderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loaderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes borderFlexLoader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderFlexLoader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes borderFlexLoader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes borderFlexLoader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes borderFlexLoader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
/*end loader 1*/

/*loader2*/

.loader2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
.loader2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #457AA6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-animation: loader2BorderRotate 1.5s infinite ease;
  -moz-animation: loader2BorderRotate 1.5s infinite ease;
  -webkit-animation: loader2BorderRotate 1.5s infinite ease;
  -ms-animation: loader2BorderRotate 1.5s infinite ease;
  animation: loader2BorderRotate 1.5s infinite ease;
}
.loader2:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #457AA6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-animation: loader2BorderRotate 3s infinite ease reverse;
  -ms-animation: loader2BorderRotate 3s infinite ease reverse;
  -webkit-animation: loader2BorderRotate 3s infinite ease reverse;
  -moz-animation: loader2BorderRotate 3s infinite ease reverse;
  animation: loader2BorderRotate 3s infinite ease reverse;
}
@-o-keyframes loader2BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader2BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader2BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes loader2BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loader2BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/*end loader2*/

/*loader3*/

.loader3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
.loader3:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2D9D31;
  border-left: 3px solid #2D9D31;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loader3BorderRotate 2s infinite;
}
.loader3:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #2D9D31;
  border-right: 3px solid #2D9D31;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loader3BorderRotate 2s infinite reverse;
}
@-o-keyframes loader3BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader3BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader3BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes loader3BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loader3BorderRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/*end loader3*/

/*loader4*/

.loader4 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
.loader4:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  margin: -2px;
  -o-animation: loader4 1s infinite ease;
  -moz-animation: loader4 1s infinite ease;
  -webkit-animation: loader4 1s infinite ease;
  -ms-animation: loader4 1s infinite ease;
  animation: loader4 1s infinite ease;
}
.loader4:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  -o-animation: loader4 1.5s infinite ease;
  -moz-animation: loader4 1.5s infinite ease;
  -webkit-animation: loader4 1.5s infinite ease;
  -ms-animation: loader4 1.5s infinite ease;
  animation: loader4 1.5s infinite ease;
}
@-o-keyframes loader4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes loader4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loader4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/*end loader4*/

/*loader 5*/

.loader5 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loader5 1.5s infinite ease reverse;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
.loader5:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  margin: -3px;
  animation: loader5 3s infinite ease reverse;
}
.loader5:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: #000;
  animation: loader5 3s infinite ease;
}
@keyframes loader5 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/*end loader5*/

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader1"></div>
<div class="loader2"></div>
<div class="loader3"></div>
<div class="loader4"></div>
<div class="loader5"></div>
```

Comment: It would...although the square doesn't change size, the effective height does...due to Pythagoras.

Comment: @Paulie_D It only happens in Chrome though. I can understand why this would happen but I don't understand why it is only Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the loaders are centered using `margin:auto`, when the screen height is not enough, you will notice the flexing effect. Check the below image from chrome dev tools:

[image]

Solution: wrap all loaders in a div and give it `overflow:hidden`

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="loader1"></div>
  <div class="loader2"></div>
  <div class="loader3"></div>
  <div class="loader4"></div>
  <div class="loader5"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/6b4bedde261053dd43e26faded7adc87/)**